# Add row from datagridview1 to datagridview2

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two datagridviews in one from. I need to get data from database to datagridview1 (using Select *from database...) then I want to add data from datagriwview to datagridview2 using Selected Rows.

First I wanted to solve this problem to get Selected Row's ID, when I select row in datagridview it shows in datagridview2, but when I select another row, it is updating in datagridview, it does not add as new row. I tried several ways but did not solve this problem, Is there anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {


        int id = Convert.ToInt32

  (dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["id"].Value);//3

        try
        {

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
            MySqlCommand command = start.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT id, muayine_adi, sabit_qiymet FROM tibbi_xidmetler  WHERE id = '" + id.ToString() + "'";

            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter oxu = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                oxu.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is quite simple the explanation: everytime that you make a double click to a datagridview1's cell you replace the old datatable with a new one. If you want append the result you can do something like this:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
MySqlCommand command = start.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT id, muayine_adi, sabit_qiymet FROM tibbi_xidmetler  WHERE id = '" + id.ToString() + "'";
conn.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter oxu = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
oxu.Fill(dt);
if(dataGridView2.DataSource != null) {
    DataTable pr = dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable;
    pr.Merge(dt);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = pr;
}
else
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working, but when I click row twice, it does not update, it is still inserting same row :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all information in datagridview1 you should just copy the contents of the selected row into a new row for datagridrow2.

The DataGridView is based on a DataSet which contains DataTables. 
The DataTable contains rows.
You cannot move a row from one table to annother.
Instead you have to create a new row and insert into the DataTable of DataGridView2

Comment: Ho can I copy the contents of the selected row?

Comment: I'd use a small loop, copy each "field" row2[n] = row1[n];

Comment: I am new at C# programming, could you give me an example?

Comment: You can find the copy part in Senthilkumar's solution

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

                if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value != null)
                {
                    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value);

                    MySqlConnection start = new MySqlConnection(baglanti);
                    MySqlCommand command = start.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT id, muayine_adi, sabit_qiymet FROM tibbi_xidmetler  WHERE id = '" + Id + "'";
                    start.Open();
                    MySqlDataAdapter oxu = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    oxu.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        int idx = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1;
                        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(dt.Rows.Count);
                        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            int rVal = (idx + i) + 1;
                            dataGridView2.Rows[rVal].Cells["id"].Value = dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
                            dataGridView2.Rows[rVal].Cells["muayine_adi"].Value = dt.Rows[i]["muayine_adi"].ToString();
                            dataGridView2.Rows[rVal].Cells["sabit_qiymet"].Value = dt.Rows[i]["sabit_qiymet"].ToString();
                        }

                    }
                    start.Close();
                }
        }
```

Comment: thanks, but row does not update, I can still add same row twice :(

Comment: I did not get you. I am new at C# proqramming

Comment: ok, u can check same id will repeat or not and then you may add

Comment: in you DB which format you maintain integer or varchar to check

Comment: id is integer, second field is varchar, third field is float

Comment: I checked different field, which one is integer, but it is not working, how can I check if id already exists in datagridview2?

Comment: Sorry Ali ismayilov 2 days holiday i cant response to you -- integer pass without single colon then try

Comment: Senthilkumar, thank you for you attention, my problem has already been solved )

Comment: which country you from